# Strictly convex function in two variables, do the points where the function is partially optimized in one variable trace out a straight line?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, affine-geometry

Suppose $f(x,y):\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is strictly convex in 
$(x,y)$. It is known that the function:

$g(x)=\inf_{y}f(x,y)=\min_{y}f(x,y)$

is convex in $x$, provided $g(x) > -\infty$ for all $x$. However, I am wondering if it is also the case that the set:

$H=\{(x,y):y=argmin_{y}f(x,y)\}$

is necessarily a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$. I think it's impossible for $H$ to trace out a curve while still preserving convexity, but it seems difficult to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, consider
$$f(x,y) = (x-y)^2 + e^{x+y}$$
Three approximate points on $H$ are $(-1,-1.06)$, $(0,-0.37)$ and $(1,-0.15)$, which are not on a line.

Comment: Hmm, true. I should have specified "f(x,y) attains a global minimum on R^2". Cheers.

Comment: @ghiufhe that doesn't change the answer, since you could modify the second term of my function so it becomes some decreasing convex function left of $x+y=-2.07$ (and $\exp(x+y)$ right of $x+y=-2.07$).

Comment: Thanks! Seems so intuitively weird to me that it can be convex with the partial minimum twisting around like that. From a mental image perspective, all I can picture is a twisting halfpipe which can never be convex. Oh well, guess I'm wrong.

Comment: @ghiufhe it is convex if you project the trajectory on $x$ space